# Getting keys from Firebase query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having problem getting keys from queried results. This is my Firebase Database structure:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3" : {
      "dPicture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Profile_images%2Fcropped1465266876.jpg?alt=media&token=44f83fdf-935a-4b3c-8138-561dcba2fca7",
      "status" : "hi my name is erik",
      "uid" : "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3",
      "username" : "erik"
    }
  },
  "posts" : {
    "-KfsrGsY8TWb2wiMFtAq" : {
      "dPicture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Profile_images%2Fcropped1465266876.jpg?alt=media&token=44f83fdf-935a-4b3c-8138-561dcba2fca7",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Post_Images%2Fcropped1354055061.jpg?alt=media&token=77fbc9ed-4356-43c1-b7bb-9563300a8b7b",
      "small_title" : "tes",
      "summary" : "tes",
      "title" : "tes",
      "uid" : "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3",
      "username" : "erik"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get `KfsrGsY8TWb2wiMFtAq`, but using this code below

```
Query mThisUsersPosts;

public static final String TAG = "blah" ;

mDatabasePosts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");

mThisUsersPosts = mDatabasePosts.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(mCurrentUser);

mThisUsersPosts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      final String posts_key = dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString();
                      Log.d(TAG,posts_key);
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                  }
              });
```

I don't understand why instead of getting the result I am getting random callbacks such as:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot$1@cfbcf64
com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot$1@961642a
com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot$1@6f0d191
```

Many thanks beforehand!

Comment: you can get item key from datasnapshot like datasnapshot.getKey();

Comment: Hi @Mohom.R ... tried it... it's returning "posts" haha... one level too high

Comment: I have posted a answer please look at it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. So you need to iterate over the children of the returned snapshot to get the individual result(s).

```
mThisUsersPosts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getKey());
            System.out.println(child.child("title").getValue());
        }
    }
```

Note that I wonder if the data structure you picked is right for your app though. If your main use-case is to display the posts for a specific user, consider modeling the data as such:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3" : {
      "dPicture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Profile_images%2Fcropped1465266876.jpg?alt=media&token=44f83fdf-935a-4b3c-8138-561dcba2fca7",
      "status" : "hi my name is erik",
      "uid" : "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3",
      "username" : "erik"
    }
  },
  "posts" : {
    "7idb6ThWR8aqmnEHFao5GRCV1kI3": {
      "-KfsrGsY8TWb2wiMFtAq" : {
        "dPicture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Profile_images%2Fcropped1465266876.jpg?alt=media&token=44f83fdf-935a-4b3c-8138-561dcba2fca7",
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/parkir-ngasal.appspot.com/o/Post_Images%2Fcropped1354055061.jpg?alt=media&token=77fbc9ed-4356-43c1-b7bb-9563300a8b7b",
        "small_title" : "tes",
        "summary" : "tes",
        "title" : "tes",
        "username" : "erik"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this structure you can get the posts for the user with the much simpler/faster construct:

```
mThisUsersPosts = mDatabasePosts.child(mCurrentUser);

mThisUsersPosts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(child.getKey());
            System.out.println(child.child("title").getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I need.

Eventhough  I've achieved the desired result. Yes your suggestion is way better (wish I could upvote twice). How do I pass the user uid to set as the "posts" key?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to iterate on posts to get  key of individual post

```
for(Datasnapshot snap : datasnapshot.getChildren()){
    String key = snap.getKey();
     Post post =snap.getValue(Post.class);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mohom.R thank you for the answer... it is definitely what I should do although Frank van Puffelen's answer is more relevant as he is using my situation as the answer so I can't accept your answer as the answer but I shall upvote this!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

```
//This assumes Post is the data type you're trying to get.
final Posts posts = dataSnapshot.getValue(Posts.class);
```

If you have multiple posts you can do:

```
for(Datasnapshot data : datasnapshot.getChildren()){
     Post post = data.getValue(Posts.class);
  }
```

From there you can get anything you need. This is the nice thing about Firebase, is that it will build your model for you. So you can do things like `posts.getPostTile()` and `posts.getPostSummary()`. It's really handy.

Comment: Hi BlackHatSamurai... thanks for the answer... Sorry I don't understand what's the Posts.class? Do I have to create that class

I am trying to get the data from the Firebase database as shown in my Json posted in my question (sorry if I am not understanding something that's supposed to be very simple as I am still fairly new to Android programming and Firebase hehe)

Comment: @Jagmaster its the class of whatever data type you are trying to get. I used Posts as an example. What every the class of data is that you stored, that is what you put there.